# Is it's possible to do particular replication in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 10.1 DB. I need to do particular replication depend on column values.

```
SourceDB:
id sex
1  m
2  m
3  f
```

I need to do replication on update/insert of new columns depends on `sex` field to get 2 target DB:

```
TargetMale:
1 m
2 m

TargetFemale:
3 f
```

I want to replicate piece of table located on another server. Real world examples I have tons of payment transactions and some software that process it. Transaction with status `success` and `fail` are processing in different wayб roughly speaking.

Is it's possible to do with PG?

Comment: You can write a trigger to solve your purpose

Comment: You want to replicate a piece of table? As in replicate to another database instance? I really would like to see a real life example of that. Anyway you can write a trigger that dispatches each insert/update to a separate table and replicate those. With inheritance you can still use the main table for reads.

Comment: I think you will need [pglogical](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/) for that.